# How to get user Seller ID, Marketplace ID and MWS token?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, payment-gateway, amazon-mws

I am not familiar with amazon API's. I am building web app and I want to get user Seller ID, Marketplace ID and MWS token when he/she register on my web app. On time of register he and she will redirect to [this site](https://sellercentral.amazon.ca/gp/mws/registration/register.html?signInPageDisplayed=1&devAuth=1) where user can login and submit agreement and then redirect to my web site with information of Seller ID, Marketplace ID and MWS token.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

The [MWS FAQ](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/faq.html#mawsportal-faq-mwsCredentials) describes both how to get your own IDs and tokens, as well as the process of adding a third-party web application to your Amazon Merchant account.